# Insert data from stdout of running process into sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite, stdout

I found several posts on reading the stdout while a process is running using subprocess in Python. However none of them including communicate()[0] worked. I am trying to read a continuous stdout in realtime and insert the data in a database. I am willing to allow some buffering.

Thanks
Chandrayee

Comment: `for data in iter(proc.stdout.readline, '')` making sure you are using `stdout=PIPE`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a bit slow, but it works.